# Improve surface plot visualisation of scatter points

Tags: matlab, plot, surface, 4d

I want to visualize 4 vectors of scattered data with a surface plot. 3 vectors should be the coordinates. In addition the 4th vector should represent a surface color.
My first approach was to plot this data (xk,yk,zk,ck) using

```
scatHand = scatter3(xk,yk,zk,'*');    
set(scatHand, 'CData', ck);   
caxis([min(ck), max(ck)])
```

As a result I get scattered points of different color. As these points lie on the surface of a hemisphere it ist possible to get colored faces instead of just points. I replace the scattered points by a surface using griddata to first build an approximation

```
xk2=sort(unique(xk));   
yk2=sort(unique(yk));   
[xxk, yyk]=meshgrid(xk2, yk2);   
zzk=griddata(xk,yk,zk,xxk,yyk,'cubic');  
cck=griddata(xk,yk,clr,xxk,yyk,'cubic');     
surf(xxk,yyk,zzk,cck);  
shading flat;
```

This is already nearly what I want except that the bottom of the hemisphere is ragged. Of course if I increase the interpolation point numbers it gets better but than the handling of the plot gets also slow. So I wonder if there is an easy way to force the interpolation function to do a clear break. In addition it seems that the ragged border is because the value of zzk gets 'NaN' outside the circle the hemisphere shares with the z=0-plane.
[image: Hemisphere surface built out of scattered data]

The red points at the top are the first several entries of the original scattered data.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ZLim` option to slice the plotted values within a certain range.

```
set(gca, 'Zlim', [min_value max_value])
```

[image]